# How to solve BibTex showing problem

Tags: bibtex

I have an issue with my references, I have tried many `bibliographystyle`, but no good solution , following images shows my problem.

[image]
the tex file :

```
%
% ****** maiksamp.tex 29.11.2001 ******
%
\documentclass[
aps,%
12pt,%
final,%
notitlepage,%
oneside,%
onecolumn,%
nobibnotes,%
nofootinbib,% 
superscriptaddress,%
noshowpacs,%
centertags]%
{revtex4}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[hyperpageref]{backref}
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\graphicspath{ {figures/} }


\begin{document}




\nocite{*}
\bibliography{bibfile}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

the bib file :

```
    @inproceedings{yuan2010security,
      title={Security monitoring around a video surveillance car with a pair of two-camera omni-directional imaging devices},
      author={Yuan, Pei-Hsuan and Yang, Kuo-Feng and Tsai, Wen-Hsiang},
      booktitle={Computer Symposium (ICS), 2010 International},
      pages={325--330},
      year={2010},
      organization={IEEE}
    }
    @inproceedings{banu2017intelligent,
      title={Intelligent video surveillance system},
      author={Banu, Virgil Claudiu and Costea, Ilona M{\u{a}}d{\u{a}}lina and Nemtanu, Florin Codrut and B{\u{a}}descu, Iulian},
      booktitle={Design and Technology in Electronic Packaging (SIITME), 2017 IEEE 23rd International Symposium for},
      pages={208--212},
      year={2017},
      organization={IEEE}
    }
```

Comment: Not at pc, but what happens if you outcomment abntex2cite and/or the backref packages, clear files and recompile?

Comment: no I do not need abntex2cite, I'm just trying to find a solution to this

Comment: I have used natbib and runthe BibTeX, I got `Process started

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6500 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary file: paper.aux I couldn't open style file natbib.bst ---line 47 of file paper.aux : \bibstyle{natbib : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I found no style file---while reading file paper.aux (There were 2 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `revtex4` document class loads the `natbib` citation management package automatically (with the option `sort&compress`). Nothing good is going to come from loading another citation management package, such as `abntex2cite`. In short: don't load this package if you have to use the `revtex4` document class.

The following example employs the `plain` bibliography style to format the two bibliographic entries at hand. You may, or may not, be free to use any other bibliography style that produces numeric-style citation call-outs.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibfile.bib}
@inproceedings{yuan2010security,
  title        = "Security monitoring around a video surveillance car
                  with a pair of two-camera omni-directional
                  imaging devices",
  author       = "Yuan, Pei-Hsuan and Yang, Kuo-Feng and Tsai,
                  Wen-Hsiang",
  booktitle    = "Computer Symposium (ICS), 2010 International",
  pages        = "325--330",
  year         = 2010,
  organization = "IEEE",
}
@inproceedings{banu2017intelligent,
  title        = "Intelligent video surveillance system",
  author       = "Banu, Virgil Claudiu and Costea, Ilona
                  M{\u a}d{\u a}lina and Nemtanu, Florin Codrut
                  and B{\u a}descu, Iulian",
  booktitle    = "Design and Technology in Electronic Packaging
                  (SIITME), 2017 IEEE 23rd International Symposium
                  for",
  pages        = "208--212",
  year         = 2017,
  organization = "IEEE",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[aps,12pt,final,notitlepage,%
       oneside,onecolumn,nobibnotes,nofootinbib,%
       superscriptaddress,noshowpacs,centertags,%
      ]{revtex4}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{graphicx,adjustbox}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{array,multirow,booktabs,makecell}

%\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}  %% <-- this is the source of the problems
%\usepackage{natbib} %% is loaded automatically by revtex4 document class
\bibliographystyle{plain} %% or any other suitable bibliography style

%% Load the next two packages **last**:
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyperpageref]{backref}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{bibfile}
\end{document}
```